# im sending msg back to main UI thread but failed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i m send message to main UI thread through worker thread but it gives these errors

```
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): Process: com.example.threadproject, PID: 1156
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.example.threadproject.MyThread.PostMsg(MyThread.java:113)
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.example.threadproject.MyThread.dials(MyThread.java:64)
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.example.threadproject.MainThread.Function(MainThread.java:39)
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.example.threadproject.MainThread.access$0(MainThread.java:35)
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at com.example.threadproject.MainThread$1.onClick(MainThread.java:28)
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-04 11:59:00.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1156):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
```

the code is

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{

    Handler mHandler  ;
    Handler mHandlerMain = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());



    public void run() 
        {
            Looper.prepare();
            PostMainThreadMsg();                    
            mHandler = new Handler() 
            {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                    Log.i("Message", "" + msg);
                    //PostMainThreadMsg();              
                }
             };

            Looper.loop();

        }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        public class Dial implements Runnable
        {
            int m_nLine;


            public int m_bResult;

            public void run()
            {
                Log.v("dial","class run");

                m_nLine++;

                RunnableNotify(this);
            }
        }


        public int dials(int nLine) 
        {
            startThread();

            Dial m_objDial = new Dial();

            m_objDial.m_nLine = nLine;


            PostMsg(m_objDial);

            return m_objDial.m_bResult ;

        }

    public void PostMainThreadMsg()
    {
//      mHandlerMain .post(new Runnable() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              Message msg = Message.obtain();
//              msg.arg1 = 5;
//              mHandlerMain.sendMessage(msg);
//              
//          }
//      }); super.start();

        Runnable n_obj = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Message msg =  Message.obtain();
                msg.arg1 = 20;  
                mHandlerMain.sendMessage(msg);



            }
        };
        PostMssg(n_obj);


    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        public void PostMssg(Runnable runnable)
        {
            mHandlerMain.post(runnable);

        }

        public void PostMsg(Runnable runnable)
        {
            mHandler.post(runnable);

            RunnableWait(runnable);


        }

        public void startThread()
        {

            super.start();

        }
```

Comment: which is line 113 in MyThread?

Answer (score 0):

In `Dials` you start the thread, and then call `PostMsg` which uses `mHandler`. But `mHandler` is only initialised within the thread (in your first `run` method).

So there's a race; there's no guarantee that the initialisation will have happened before the use. (And in any case if you assign to a variable in one thread, the result may not be visible in the other thread.)

This isn't hard to diagnose - you know `mHandler` is null, so you just need to work back to see where it should be initialised, and then see if there's any way for the initialisation not to have happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use `AsyncTask`.
Managing the process is easier, too.
Any questions, please feel free to comment :)